# String manipulation issue in sql removing underscore and characters after that from comma delimited string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to change a string which is in the format say :

```
"12_7,34_22,28_4,6_22"
```

TO

```
"12,34,28,6"
```

Essentially I want to eliminate "_" (underscore and whatever is after that and before comma ) from the string. Haven't worked with sql so it is looking like an uphill task to me.

Comment: Which RDBMS exactly are you using?

Comment: Is it necessary to do it in SQL?

Comment: I am using sql server2005. Yes i need to do it in sql.

Comment: Are you looking for a purely SQL solution?  This is something that would typically best be done pragmatically in your application logic.

Comment: Yes its a part of ssrs cascading parameter issues I have been trying to resolve for a long time. This is the only thing I need to resolve in sql for that to work. Tried many different ways but the sql change is the only thing that will work for the ssrs issue.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  There may be something else that can be done.  For instance, are you using the string to find values in it?

Comment: The 2nd string contains the real codes. For the ssrs issue to resolve I had to add the "_Rownumber()" part to each code the user selected. . So the multiple selected codes ends up in this format which is passed on to the next sql. But the real codes that I have to use is contained in the 2nd string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION DeUnderscore(@s nvarchar(max))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @iu int = CHARINDEX('_', @s); -- position of _
    DECLARE @ic int = CHARINDEX(',', @s, @iu) -- position of ,  
    WHILE (@iu != 0)
    BEGIN
        IF @ic = 0 SET @ic = LEN(@s) + 1; -- if there's no , go to end of string
        SET @s = STUFF(@s, @iu, @ic - @iu, ''); -- replace everything after _ and before , with ''
        SET @iu = CHARINDEX('_', @s);
        SET @ic = CHARINDEX(',', @s, @iu)
    END 
    RETURN @s
END
```

..in use it would look like..

```
SELECT dbo.DeUnderscore(myValue) AS myCleanedValue FROM myTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look a defining your own functionin MySQL.  This would allow you to write out a set of commands inside the function which could utilize the DB's inherent string manipulation functions and output the desired result.  For example you could define a function like myStringFunction, and within that function find the index locations of all the underscores and commas, then pull out the desired substrings and concatenate them together again.  You usage in a query could then be like.

SELECT myStringFunction(field_name) FROM table;

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @str varchar(100)='12_7,34_22,28_4,6_22'
DECLARE @out varchar(100)=''
While(CHARINDEX('_',@str,1) > 0)
begin
SET @out=@out+LEFT(REPLACE(@str,SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX('_',@str,1),CHARINDEX(',',@str,1)-CHARINDEX('_',@str,1)),''),CHARINDEX(',',REPLACE(@str,SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX('_',@str,1),CHARINDEX(',',@str,1)-CHARINDEX('_',@str,1)),'')))
SET @str=RIGHT(REPLACE(@str,SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX('_',@str,1),CHARINDEX(',',@str,1)-CHARINDEX('_',@str,1)),''),LEN(REPLACE(@str,SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX('_',@str,1),CHARINDEX(',',@str,1)-CHARINDEX('_',@str,1)),''))-CHARINDEX(',',REPLACE(@str,SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX('_',@str,1),CHARINDEX(',',@str,1)-CHARINDEX('_',@str,1)),'')))

end
select @out+@str
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution with out while loop

```
declare @str varchar(30)='12_7,34_22,28_4,6_22,8_545'

;with cte (startPos,strg) as(
 select CHARINDEX('_',@str,1) [startPos],cast(@str as varchar(500)) as [strg]
 union all
 select CHARINDEX('_',[strg],[startPos])+1 [startPos],cast(stuff([strg],
 CHARINDEX('_',[strg],[startPos]),CHARINDEX(',',[strg],
 [startPos])-CHARINDEX('_',[strg],[startPos]),'') as varchar(500)) as [strg] 
 from cte
 where  CHARINDEX('_',[strg],[startPos])>0
)
select substring(MIN(strg),1,CHARINDEX('_',MIN(strg),1)-1) from cte
```